# javascript to detect a browser and use a certain style sheet

Tags: javascript, css, margin

There is a a single element of a web page that I absolutely MUST have sit in a precise location on the page, and there seems to be a 14px height differential between Chrome and FF which won't allow me to situate the graphic uniformly between the two. I used a conditional statement for IE9 and IE8, but now the problem exists with Chrome and FF.

I don't have access to the main head section or main global CSS for this site, unfortunately, and there is not a global reset of 0 on the margins. Even if it were possible for me to do so, there have been so many hacks and fixes, that it would be counter-productive to do a global reset.

So after messing around with musical chairs of this object, I think my final solution (although not very elegant to do for just ONE graphic) is to write a style sheet for the margin-top of this image (actually a div with an image background), and have javascript detect the browser and feed the style-sheet accordingly (i.e. - if it is FF then render this CSS, or if it is Chrome then render this CSS).

Unfortunately I cannot show the page, but my CSS for the element is:

```
    #telescope {
    background: url("my-image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 102px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -48px;
    margin-top: 748px;
    width: 98px;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: btw, I already did try the top:0px; and left:0px; in this particular CSS, to no avail.

Comment: `if(chrome.webstore)` would likely do, but I'd still prefer feature detection and cross browser valid css to that if I were you.

Comment: have you tried padding-top 0?

Comment: Sounds a bit funny to me, if already using Javascript to detect the browser, then feed a certain style sheet, instead of just setting the needed (top) margin on the respective element! BTW: [**Browserhacks**](http://browserhacks.com/) is worth to have a look ...!

Comment: Even if you cannot show the page, certainly you can show an extract which demonstrates the problem, without which it is very hard to respond.

Comment: A clip of the page http://salter.biz/images/tele.png. The image of this telescope needs to sit exactly on the green line. It does in Chrome for Mac, but not for FF (on Windows or Mac). The CSS is above...and I did set the margins on the element, however this is the problem Netsurfer, because the margins do not work in all of the browsers. I fixed the IE 8 and 9 with conditionals, but need to know the way about how to use JavaScript (or some CSS prefereably) to make sure that this graphic is positioned the same in all browsers. -moz -webkit do not work with margins, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the top of your css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

font-family: "Open Sans", 'Consolas', sans-serif; 
  }

html, body {height: 100%;}
```

Comment: thanks djbhindi...but I did mention that I do not have access to the global style sheet, and furthermore it would cause havoc to the numerous hacks and band-aids that have been implemented over the years already.

Comment: My bad, didn't read that. Seems like a crappy situation, maybe better to start fresh :). Good luck with your problem.

Comment: yes I'd love to start fresh!! But, that isn't an option unfortunately. It's a very large site, with various divisions, so many chefs in the kitchen, and just a big hodge podge of stuff. This sort of thing is kind of what happens when developers are not invited to design meetings :-/